# sql query returns nothing, while it should

Tags: sql, sql-server

I run this query on *sql server 2012*

```
select * from news where category = 'فيديو';
```

I have 1,000+ records with 'فيديو' category, but it doesn't return any of them. i tried `Like` keyword to see if there are space or something, unfortunately it doesn't return any records.

also i run this query to be sure

```
select category,count(*) from news group by category;
```

and this was the result 
[image]

Note: category column have nvarchar(100) type

anyone else having same problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use N before string because 'فيديو' is unicode charactor so 
use this

```
select * from news where category = N'فيديو';
```

You may have seen Transact-SQL code that passes strings around using an N prefix. This denotes that the subsequent string is in Unicode (the N actually stands for National language character set). Which means that you are passing an NCHAR, NVARCHAR or NTEXT value, as opposed to CHAR, VARCHAR or TEXT.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
 select * from news where category = N'فيديو'; /* place N before the starting single Quotation */
```

Here Is **[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f33e92/1)**

Comment: @dotfreelancer: Check my updated answer and sqlfiddle